# Simple nested JSON parsing in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm receiving this JSON from an API:

```
{"MatchedResult":{"CurrentStatus":47}}
```

Using this code:

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
NSString *currentStatus = [responseDict objectForKey:@"CurrentStatus"];
```

Returns Null.

Using this code:

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
NSString *currentStatus = [responseDict objectForKey:@"MatchedResult"];
```

Returns:

```
{
    CurrentStatus = 47;
}
```

How do I just get the status of 47?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dig into the structure:

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
NSString *currentStatus = responseDict[@"MatchedResult"][@"CurrentStatus"];
```

Answer (score 1):

to get the value you need you have to analyze the json to get the necessary key

```
{
     "MatchedResult": {
        "CurrentStatus": 47
      }
}
```

as CurrentStatus key is needed has to go through MatchedResult

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString]; 
NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
NSString *currentStatus = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"MatchedResult"] objectForKey:@"CurrentStatus"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Response` dictionary containing a `Matched Result` dictionary containing your `CurrentStatus`.

You want...

```
NSDictionary *matchedResultDict = [responseDict objectForKey:@"MatchedResult"];
NSString *currentStatus = [matchedResultDict objectForKey:@"CurrentStatus"];
```